# Rshiny layout boxes

Tags: r, shiny

Having trouble searching the right words for this particular issue I am having.

I wanted boxes to go around this image of the car, but given the height of the image, it means it shifts the next fluidrow to be even further down. Is there a way to get the boxes to look like where I have drawn the red boxes? But more so the boxes next to the car image on row 3 (I don't expect anyone to code the 4th fluid row!).

I tried to incorporate the vertical layout but it just made everything vertical.

[image: layout]

code: and just use any image to replace below

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    dashboardBody(
      # the first row
      fluidRow(
        box( id = "box1",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box1"))),
             p(textOutput("box1_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE
        ),
        box( id = "box2",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box2"))),
             p(textOutput("box2_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE,
             background = "blue"
        ),
        box( id = "box3",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box3"))),
             p(textOutput("box3_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE
        ),
        box( id = "box4",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box4"))),
             p(textOutput("box4_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE,
             background = "yellow"
        ),
        box( id = "box5",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box5"))),
             p(textOutput("box5_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE,
             background = "purple"
        ),
        box( id = "box6",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box6"))),
             p(textOutput("box6_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE
        )
        
      ),
      br(),
      # second row with car image
      fluidRow(
        box( id = "box7",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box7"))),
             p(textOutput("box7_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE,
             background = "green"
        ),
        box( id = "box8",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box8"))),
             p(textOutput("box8_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE,
             background = "green"
        ),
        box( uiOutput("car_image"),
             width = 4
        ),
        box( id = "box13",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box13"))),
             p(textOutput("box13_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE,
             background = "green"
        ),
        box( id = "box14",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box14"))),
             p(textOutput("box14_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE,
             background = "green"
        )
      ),
      br(),
      # third row
      fluidRow(
        box( id = "box10",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box10"))),
             p(textOutput("box10_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE
        )
      ),
      br(),
      # fourth row
      fluidRow(
        box( id = "box11",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box11"))),
             p(textOutput("box11_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE
        ),
        box( id = "box12",
             h4(strong(textOutput("box12"))),
             p(textOutput("box12_sub")),
             width = 2,
             solidHeader = TRUE
        )))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
    output$car_image <- renderUI({
        img(src='/image.png', width = '100%')})

    
    output$box1 <- renderText({"box1"})
    
    output$box1_sub<- renderText({"box1_sub"})
    
    output$box2 <- renderText({"box2"})
    
    output$box2_sub <- renderText({"box2_sub"})
    
    output$box3 <- renderText({"box3"})
    
    output$box3_sub <-renderText({"box3_sub"})
    
    output$box4<- renderText({"box4"})
    
    output$box4_sub <- renderText({"box4_sub"})
    
    output$box5 <- renderText({"box5"})
    
    output$box5_sub <- renderText({"box5_sub"})

    output$box6 <- renderText({"box6_sub"})
    
    output$box6_sub <- renderText({"box6_sub"})
    
    output$box7<- renderText({"box7"})

    output$box7_sub <- renderText({"box7_sub"})

    output$box8 <- renderText({"box8"})

    output$box8_sub <- renderText({"box8_sub"})

    output$box9<- renderText({"box9"})

    output$box9_sub <- renderText({"box9_sub"})

    output$box10<- renderText({"box10"})

    output$box10_sub <- renderText({"box10_sub"})

    output$box11<- renderText({"box11"})

    output$box11_sub <- renderText({"box11_sub"})

    output$box12<- renderText({"box12"})

    output$box12_sub <- renderText({"box12_sub"})

    output$box13<- renderText({"box13"})

    output$box13_sub <- renderText({"box13_sub"})

    output$box14<- renderText({"box14"})

    output$box14_sub <- renderText({"box14_sub"})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3):

Given your code I will try to help you with other aspects of your App as well.

#### Set up

> Recommendation 1: Use funcional programming

Hadley Wickham in the [chapter 18 of his book mastering shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-functions.html#ui-functions) cover the idea of using functions to reduce code duplication in your apps. Taking this in consideration, let's build a function that taking an id as argument, returns a box.

With this function you can control any element of the box. And, with the argument `imagenbox` you can tell if the box will contain the car image.

```r
create_box <- \(
  id, imagenbox = FALSE,  width = 12, 
  background = 'green',solid_header = TRUE
  ){
  
  boxId <- paste0('box', id)
  subtilteId <- paste0('box', id, "_sub")
  
  if(imagenbox) {
    return(
      box(
        id = boxId, class = 'imagen_box',
        uiOutput('car_image'),
        width = width
        )
    )
  }
  
  box(id = boxId,
      h4(strong(textOutput(boxId))),
      p(textOutput(subtilteId)),
      width = width,
      solidHeader = solid_header
      )
}
```

Now that you have this function, let's prepare the list of argument to loop over that function and generate the boxes in you app UI.

With this two vectors we are going to create 13 boxes, and the box number 6 will be the box with the car image.

```r
boxes <- 1:13
car_imagen_index <- c(rep(FALSE, 5), TRUE, rep(FALSE, 7))
```

### App User interface

With an app as complex as this one, you have to think out of the box and use not only shiny code to arrange and style the visual elements. I will add a css file to include/make the grid layout you need.

The css file content is this

```css
/* Display grid for the box container with 4 columns   */
body > div.wrapper > div > section > div > section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

/* Element 6 (the one with the image, remember)  to span across
   two rows and columns
*/
body > div > div > section > div > section > div:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Note: A `.css` file is just a text file with that extension. [This article is a good introduction](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)

```r
ui <-  dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
  # Here I include the css file
    includeCSS('grid-style.css'),
    useShinyjs(),
    dashboardBody(
      # Function programming to generate the boxes
      map2(boxes, car_imagen_index, ~create_box(.x, .y))
    )
    )
  )
```

In your server you can use functional programming as well. For example, the title and subtitle of the boxes will be generated with a iteretive process.

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  # render the car image
  output$car_image <- renderUI({
    img(src='https://www.elcarrocolombiano.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/20210420-WORLD-CAR-OF-THE-YEAR-VOLKSWAGEN-ID-4-01.jpg', width = '100%')})
  
  # render the boxes title and subtitle
  lapply(boxes, \(id) {
    boxId = paste0('box', id)
    subtitleId = paste0('box', id, '_sub')
    
    output[[boxId]] <- renderText(boxId)
    output[[subtitleId]] <- renderText(subtitleId)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]